# Access items from an Array that is inside a Dictionary in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a Dictionary which contains an array of fruits and a Double. What I would like to be able to do is access the fruits inside the array.

How can I access items inside the `fruits` array?

```
var fruits =  ["Apple", "Oranges"]

var fruitDictionary:[String: Any] = ["fruits":fruits, "car":2.5]

print("Dictionary: \(fruitDictionary["fruits"]!)") // output: Dictionary: ["Apple", "Oranges"]
```

I tried...

```
print("Dictionary: \(fruitDictionary["fruits"[0]]!)")
```

and...

```
print("Dictionary: \(fruitDictionary["fruits[0]"]!)")
```

But no luck

Thanks

Comment: `print((fruitDictionary["fruits"] as? [String])?.first ?? "N/A") // Apple`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to access the `fruits` entry of the dictionary and cast it as an array of strings.

From there you can access the elements of the array.

```
if let array = fruitDictionary["fruits"] as? [String] {
    print(array[0])
}
```

The reason why your attempts did not work is because the values in your dictionary are of type `Any`, which might not be able to be accessed through a subscript.